# Why does foreach work here when select fails?

Tags: json, powershell

I've stored a list of attachments from my RavenDB server in the `$Response` variable.

```
[{"Size":3040,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7928/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0D0"},{"Size":2524,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7927/output-log","Metadata":{
"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0CF"},{"Size":530,"Key":"attachments/tasks-7842/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0AA"}]
```

I want to get the Key value so I can fetch the attachments.

Why can't I select the Key value like this?

```
$Response | ConvertFrom-Json | Select Key
```

All the keys look empty when I do that.

Bizarrely, it works when I use Foreach instead.

```
$Response | ConvertFrom-Json | Foreach { $_.Key }
```

I see this:

```
attachments/deployments-7928/output-log
attachments/deployments-7927/output-log
attachments/tasks-7842/output-log
```

What's the difference?

Why doesn't Select work here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because convertfrom-json does not return  array of PSObjects, it returns an array system.object[]. The array does not have a 'Key' member.

```
 Write-Output '[{"Size":3040,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7928/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0D0"},{"Size":2524,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7927/output-log","Metadata":{
"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0CF"},{"Size":530,"Key":"attachments/tasks-7842/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0AA"}]' `
| convertfrom-json | get-member
```

Output

```
   TypeName: System.Object[]
   ...
```

See, it only has the following members :

### Name

Count
Add
Address
Clear
Clone
CompareTo
Contains
CopyTo
Equals
Get
GetEnumerator
GetHashCode
GetLength
GetLongLength
GetLowerBound
GetType
GetUpperBound
GetValue
IndexOf
Initialize
Insert
Remove
RemoveAt
Set
SetValue
ToString
Item
IsFixedSize
IsReadOnly
IsSynchronized
Length
LongLength
Rank
SyncRoot

Assigning to a variable converts to TypeName: `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`
and this has a 'key' member. Powershell's built-in enumeration awareness expands this properly.

Comment: I accept that it's true, but it seems really weird. Is there a specification or a reference for that behavior somewhere?

Comment: @iain-elder I don't know _why_ this is so, but powershell-console users can get the type, that an expression or a pipeline returns, from the top line of the `get-member` output. I've updated my answer for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you assign the results to a variable first, and then pass that into `Select-Object`.

```
$response = @'
    [{"Size":3040,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7928/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0D0"},{"Size":2524,"Key":"attachments/deployments-7927/output-log","Metadata":{
    "ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0CF"},{"Size":530,"Key":"attachments/tasks-7842/output-log","Metadata":{"ContentType":"text/xml"},"Etag":"02000000-0000-0014-0000-00000000A0AA"}]
'@

$ObjectList = $response | ConvertFrom-Json;

$ObjectList | Select-Object -Property Key;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the intermediate variable assignment:

```
{$response | ConvertFrom-Json}.invokereturnasis() | select key
```

Comment: Didn't know about that, so thanks for the option, but it looks a lot weirder than the variable assignment. What else is InvokeReturnAsIs useful for?

Comment: It's admittedly kind of obscure.  Can't really think if any other good examples.  It executes the scrpt block and retuns the result as a stream of PS objects.  There's also {}.invoke() which returns a collection of PS objects, which can be useful if you need a collection instead of an array.